# namespaced method is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following type script, and when I try to call the `Player()` method I get an error saying that it doesn't exist.

> Uncaught TypeError: GameSmart.User.Player is not a function

```
namespace GameSmart {
    export class User {
        public Player(): void {
            fetch(Config.domain + '/user/player').then(response => {
                // Do some stuff
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If I do `console.log(GameSmart)` I get an object with a `User` object, and in that object it isn't there, but if I look within the `GameSmart.User.prototype` object it does show up there. Why isn't it in the `GameSmart.User` object and how can I get it there?

Comment: have you tried making it `static`?

Comment: OMG I feel super stupid, that was the issue. I forgot I am not creating an instance of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `User` in order to use its method:

```
let user = new GameSmart.User();
user.Player();
```

If you don't want that then change the class into a namespace too:

```
namespace GameSmart {
    export namespace User {
        public Player(): void {
            fetch(Config.domain + '/user/player').then(response => {
                // Do some stuff
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then it should work:

```
GameSmart.User.Player();
```

Or as @DanielA.White wrote in a comment make it static:

```
namespace GameSmart {
    export class User {
        public static Player(): void {
            fetch(Config.domain + '/user/player').then(response => {
                // Do some stuff
            });
        }
    }
}

GameSmart.User.Player();
```